# Добавить сумму трех предшествующих чисел в список

Tags: python, list

Я в питоне недавно. Нужно, чтобы в конец списка добавлялось значение суммы трех предшествующих чисел, учитывая, что первые 3 числа:1, 1, 2. ошибка в 3 строке:

```
def func(b):
    for i in a:
        b.append((i-2)+(i-1)+i)
    return b[::-1]
    
a = input()
b = [1, 1, 2]
print(func(b))
```

Comment: в пределах функции у вас нет a. А вы пытаетесь пройтись по нему циклом.

Comment: `b.append(sum(b[-3:]))
print(b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получится примерно так:

```py
def func(b):
    summ = 0 # Сумма
    count = 0 # Счетчик 3 элемента
    result = []
    for i in b: 
        result.append(i)
        summ += i
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            result.append(summ)
            count = 0
            summ = 0
    return result

# получаем список чисел через запятую
a = input().split(",")
for n, el in enumerate(in_list):
    a[n] = int(el)

print(in_list)
# обьединяем с b
b = [1, 1, 2]
b = b + a
print(func(b))
```